# Restoring Win7 to Factory Image: Good Idea?

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

Hello guys I have a dell laptop with two operating systems, ubuntu and windows 7,

currently I spend all my time in ubuntu, so I decided to resotre windows 7 to factory image, will it harm my ubuntu?

Comment: If you are "spending all your time in Ubuntu", why restore Win 7? Wipe the partitions and enjoy the extra space!

Answer (score 2):

Dell's factory image will wipe the entire drive and replace it with Windows 7.  If you do not want to do this, do not restore to factory defaults

(I've got a dell, did this once by mistake, and hell ensued)

If you're not going to use Windows 7, then I'd suggest just wiping out the Windows 7 partitions and utilizing the extra space as storage (or expand your Ubuntu to use it all), but if you still have a purpose for Windows 7, don't change anything in terms of partitioning.